# Set a class on a component from its container in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it possible to set a class on a component from its container?

I'd like to do something like this:

```
<LinkButton className="text--left">Button</LinkButton>
```

but the class `text--left` is removed by React and never gets to be in the DOM. Is there any solution better than wrapping the component with `div.text--left`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `LinkButton` a component that you made?

If so, then just treat className like you would any other prop.

For instance, your LinkButton component might look like

```
LinkButton = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <button className={this.props.className}>Whatever</button>
  }
});
```

Then `<LinkButton className="text--left">Button</LinkButton>` would render with the class you pass into it.

Comment: Aha good point. Thanks. I would need to do this with all my components though.